# Azure SignalR: HubException method does not exist

Tags: azure, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

I am finding we receive this error:

```
Failed to invoke 'CreateChatRequest' due to an error on the server. HubException: Method does not exist.
at _this.callbacks.<computed> (chat.min.js:2060)
at HubConnection.processIncomingData (chat.min.js:2154)
at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (chat.min.js:1881)
at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessage (chat.min.js:3922)
```

The method does exist. The code does work, then after a while of testing, it returns this and won't stop.

What seems to temporarily fix the issue is restarting the Azure SigR service, but it comes back.  This issue does not occur when targeting local SigR during development; it only happens against Azure SigR.

According to documentation, this seems to be a catchall error when something errors up on the server but, no exceptions are being logged. I've turned on detailed errors, but that didn't change the error coming back from the server.  I've also tried catching the exception and sending back a HubException to see what is going on, but that didn't change the error message either.

TIA for any help.

Comment: Where are you defining & hosting the SignalR Hub Methods? In Asp.Net Web API,..

Comment: The hub methods are calls back to the same web app, which in turn makes calls to an event grid.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, intermittently though which is even odder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the answer, for me, was that i'd checked in (to source control) my azure service's connection string, so other devs were also using this and pointing their versions of the API service at that azure service.  So when i ran my code sometimes azure would hit my API service with the new method in and it would work, sometimes it would hit someone else's API service and so fail because their code didn't have the new method in.

Comment: A layman's terms explanation, in my environment, I had the same SignalR Hub class in both my front end WebApp as well as another Web Api project (both .NET Core 6.0) and using Azure SignalR services. From the above answer given, I realised I hadnt copied across the same methods to both classes/projects, even though i didnt need all the Hub class methods in my WebApi project, but it seems those methods have to be present in both, otherwise we get this error. @zappa thanks for the clue...